# Symfony2 Composer Not Downloading Packages

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I was recently trying to re-install the fos:userbundle and noticed the docs have changed. They are no longer using the deps file are now referencing the new package manager composer.

I found some info about integrating composer with sf2.0.* here: 
http://knplabs.com/blog/symfony2-with-composer

After downloading the src: https://github.com/KnpLabs/symfony-with-composer

I tried adding the following to my composer.json: `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"`
as per the instructions: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

When I run `bin/vendors update` I get the following:

```
Updating dependencies
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

It does not appear to be installing the fos package. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer is a PHAR archive that takes care of installing dependencies, update them, create projects, etc. It has nothing to do with the old *bin/vendors*.

What you need to do is to [download Composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/):

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

And install your dependencies:

```
php composer.phar install
```

By the way, the *symfony-with-composer* thing you downloaded is an old version of *Symfony2 Standard Distribution* that isn't maintained anymore, as mentioned on the repository itself.

Comment: Thanks, the article I read had mentioned that the bin/vendors update has been rewritten to call composer. Also, I just noticed that the package had been installed, not sure why it said nothing to install but it did work.

Comment: I noticed that it wasn't maintained, I wasn't sure what the best option was as far as using composer. If I simply download the latest sf2.0 package and then use curl to download composer, will this work out? I know they mentioned the autoloader being handled differently, not sure if this or any other factors will give me trouble integrating

Comment: It would work for the 2.1 (which ships with Composer) but not for the 2.0. -- If you want to kick off a new project, I recommend going for the 2.1, it's in a beta version but stable enough to be used for a real project. If you decide to do so, you won't have to download the archive, a simple `php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/` will download and install it with all its dependencies.